# CruiseControl. NET Getting Unused node detected for username

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

I'm having a bit of a conundrum here.

i'm working with: CruiseControl.NET Server 1.6.7981.1

We've moved offices, and at the same time our SVN repository moved from a generic stack to our clients system that uses LDAP.

Since the change I've been unable to get CruiseControl working with SVN.

Here's what I have in my config:

```
<project ...
    <webURL>...
    <workingDirectory>...
    ...
    <sourcecontrol type="svn-change-detection">
      <svn-exe>C:\Program Files\Subversion\bin\svn.exe</svn-exe>
      <code-root-url>http://blah.blah.blah/svn/project/branches/product-lines/4.3.0</code-root-url>
      <tag-root-url>http://blah.blah.blah/svn/project/tag/4.3.0</tag-root-url>
      <build-interval>86400</build-interval>
      <username>LDAP_DOMAIN\USER</username>
      <password>AwesomePassword</password>
    </sourcecontrol>
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
[CCNet Server:ERROR] Exception: Unused node detected: <username>LDAP_DOMAIN\USER</username>
```

From examples I've seen that should be perfectly legal... or am I  missing something?

Any help would rock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration is all wrong. You should review the documentation for the SVN block. Try this.

```
<sourcecontrol type="svn">
  <executable>C:\Program Files\Subversion\bin\svn.exe</executable>
  <trunkUrl>http://blah.blah.blah/svn/project/branches/product-lines/4.3.0</trunkUrl>          
  <username>LDAP_DOMAIN\USER</username>
  <password>AwesomePassword</password>
</sourcecontrol>
```

build-interval: that's part of your project config, not source control.

Comment: These were the config settings used in CruiseControl.NET 1.4 and it worked perfectly fine with the version of SVN we were using. Now that we've upgraded SVN, and new servers and cruise control, you're right I might have to look into it. I was hoping it would be backwards compatible.

Comment: Those tags were in place for a custom CruiseControlNET C# application that was called through NANT. It seems CCNET can do all this with default configurations without the need for those external tasks. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That makes sense, a lot of the CCNET plugins don't work well (or at all) when you upgrade. Glad it worked out for you.